# (Python) Turning items in a list into lists

Tags: python

I want to store items in my list as list themselves (i.e. each binary bit will be an index in the new list) but I can't seem to make that happen:

```py
encoded = []
for value in redChannelData:
    encoded1 = bin(value)[2:]
    encoded.append(encoded1)

redchannelbinarylist = [[] for binary in encoded] 

print(redchannelbinarylist)
print(encoded)
```

Output

```py
['101110', '110001', '110010', '110011', '110101', '110101', '110110', '111000', '111011', '111011', '111100', '111101', '111110', '111110', '1000000', '1000000', '1000001']
```

I want something like this:

```
[[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], ...]
```

Comment: Try `encoded.append(list(encoded1))`

Comment: That gives you a list of strings @L3viathan

Comment: You just need to finish that list comprehension, [[int(b) for b in binary] for binary in encoded]

Comment: Rather [[int(b) for b in binary] for binary in encoded] since he wants them as integers in the final list of lists.

Comment: Bah, it's cheating to update your comment while I write a comment about it :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
[list(map(int, x)) for x in a]
```

Here is what happens (from inside out):

- `list(map(int, x))` converts a list of '0' and '1' into a list of their integer equivalents. The `list` here is to get a list instead of `map` result.
- In the outer list comprehension I do the above step for each element of a

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
a = ['101110', '110001', '110010', '110011', '110101', '110101', '110110',...]
result = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    ls = []
    for k in range(len(a[i])):
        ls.append(a[i][k])
    result.append(ls)

print(result)
```

this method is a bit longer, but the logic is easy to understand.